# Peticion asíncrona en vuejs me imprime [object Promise] en html

Tags: html5, vue.js, fetch, async

Esto es **lo que intenté**:

```
<p class="item" v-for="item in asiento.debe.split(',')" :key="item">
    {{ item }}: {{ getAccount(item) }}
</p>
```

- **Aclaraciones:**
- Busco que en cada parrafo me quede algo asi:
  101: Caja
  105: Banco cuenta corriente
  205: Proveedores
- asiento.debe es un string lleno de ID's separados por comas
- Dichos ID's pertenecen a una tabla llamada "accounts" con las columnas: id | name
- La funcion getAccount() hace una peticion http a la base de datos, intenta obtener el nombre de dicha cuenta
- "item" contiene efectivamente el ID de la cuenta

metodo getAccount() del componente:

```
async getAccount (id) {
    let response = await fetch(`/accounts/${id}`);
    let data = await response.json(); 
    let account = data.name;
    console.log(account);
    return account;
}
```

**Lo que quiero** es imprimir en el html, el nombre de la cuenta, para ello uso el `console.log(account)` para ver el valor que almacena dicha variable. Y funciona, la variable `account` contiene el nombre de la cuenta.
**El problema** esta en que en el html, a pesar de que account contiene el nombre de la cuenta, en su lugar, me devuelve:

```
[object Promise]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que `getAccount` es una función async, por lo que estás devolviendo una Promise a la que deberías también hacerle `await`.